# Qualtrics: How to move to the left the div/table without affecting other page

Tags: css

I'm trying to move one single div in the left and remove the vertical scroll at the bottom without affecting other page divs/table using css

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `position: relative` property can achieve this. [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Essentially `position:relative` will say 'position the content as it would ordinarily be position, but offset left/right/up/down x amount'.

Alternatively, you can use negative margin.